# Android ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, actionbardrawertoggle

I am a complete beginner and wanted to know about actionbardrawer where we have "setDrawerLister()" and "syncState()" these two methods.
what does this method actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these link use of syncState and this you can assume  It will synchronize the icon from the drawer and the drawer itself where when you move the drawer the icon rotate, try to remove the syncState and those animation wont work